# Which is the best MVC v.2 learning source?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I would appreciate some suggestions  about useful sources for learning the new features of MVC v.2 Beta .
and the real question is how to learn the features of the MVC 2 before release ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So recently Scott Guthrie posted some articles about MVC 2 which I think is the beat source to start with MVC 2 :
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/10/asp-net-mvc-2.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Scott Hanselman has a good series of screencasts [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCPreview2ScreencastTutorials.aspx)

Also a good video from the latest PDC [here](http://microsoftpdc.com/Sessions/FT22)

Answer (score 1):

- Download the beta and try it out
- Read blogs of MVC team guys

Scott Gu's: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/tags/MVC/default.aspx

Phil Haack: http://haacked.com

And others.

- Watch related questions here on SO
- Try it yourself on real projects

By the time it's released and there are books published and available, many early adopters won't even need a book.

Comment: And still - some tips would be nice. More like designing and structuring app when using things like Templates. You know - another nerddinner or blog app that leverages use of whole new feature set. :/